# Question about basis/unit vector

Tags: notation, vectors

So if I have like the vector $(2,3)$ what does this really mean?

Because I watched a 3brown1blue video and in it he said a way to represent vectors is that the $2$ and $3$ are just scalars for the unit/basis vectors ($i$ and $j$), so it can also just be $2i + 3j.$ Now my question is when I write $(2,3)$, does this mean like going to the right $2$ in the $x$-axis and up $3$ in the $y$-axis, or does it mean $2i + 3j\,$?

He even says "but for now right I just want you to appreciate the fact that anytime we describe vectors numerically it depends on an implicit choice of what basis vectors we're using." I always thought that $(3,1)$ means I'm going to the right $3$ and up $1$, but according to him that's not the case and it depends on what basis vectors we're using.

Now I already asked this once but nobody really answered my question. When I have the vector $(3,2)$, does this mean $3$ to the right one up or does it mean $3*i + 2*j$ ($i$ and $j$ being unit/basis vectors)? Because in the video it says "but for now right I just want you to appreciate the fact that anytime we describe vectors numerically it depends on an implicit choice of what basis vectors we're using," so it seems like it's the latter. I'm just not sure.

Comment: This is difficult for many students, because you are now asked to somewhat unlearn what you already learned in more basic schooling. In basic classes the answer to *"when I write (2,3) does this mean going to the right 2 along the x-axis and up 3 along the y-axis?"* is YES. But now in more advanced work the answer is MAYBE, and to decide YES or NO in a specific context you must ask the second question *"In which system of basis vectors have we chosen to work?"*

Answer (score 1):

Because there is an arbitrary choice of basis vectors that we need to make in order to represent the vector space $\mathbb R^2$, we often simply default to the choice that is the most obvious, namely the unit vectors in the $x$ and $y$ directions. This choice $i = (1,0),j=(0,1)$ is called the **standard basis** for $\mathbb R^2$, and is usually intended unless otherwise specified. Thus, the expression $(2,3)$ does mean $2i+3j$, in the standard basis.

However, we may also want to consider the case where we pick another set of basis vectors for $\mathbb R^2$, and in this basis (different from the standard one) we will also end up getting another numerical set of coordinates for the vector. So, the issue is simply whether we are using the standard basis or not; and in most cases, the answer is implicitly "yes".

Comment: Ok so now that I'm learning linear algebra (2,3) doesn't mean 2 to the right 3 up it means 2i + 3j and because the basis vectors we usually use are just (1,0) and (0,1) then both ways work but (2,3) is just 2i + 3j right depending on what i and j are? I know I'm kinda just repeating what you said but I just wanna make sure I understood

Comment: @jayblosem11 Yes, that's correct.